# Is there any good method to resize and reposition pictures?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I have a big background picture with two black blocks and two small pictures to cover the black blocks in a div tag. I want to implement the result that I can use the input tag as range to resize all pictures and two small pictures will be repositioned to cover the black block. The size will be increased correctly, but the positions are not correct.

[when the zoom is 40%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fud2.jpg)

[when the zoom is 50%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auQZY.jpg)

[when the zoom is 100%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRVQK.jpg)

the code is shown below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    #box {
        width:300px;
        height:300px;
    }
</style>

<script>
function load()
{
    var range = document.getElementById('range');
    var zoom = document.getElementById('zoom');

    zoom.innerHTML = range.value + "%";
}

function get()
{
    var range = document.getElementById('range');
    var zoom = document.getElementById('zoom');
    var box = document.getElementById('box');
    var new_w;
    var new_h;
    var new_top;
    var new_left;
    zoom.innerHTML = range.value + "%";

    var myimg = box.getElementsByTagName('img');
    for(var i=0; i < myimg.length; i++){
        if(i == 0){
            new_w = (300 * 2 * range.value / 100);
            new_h = (300 * 2 * range.value / 100);
        }
        else if(i == 1){
            new_w = 58 * 2 * range.value / 100;
            new_h = 48 * 2 * range.value / 100;
            new_top = 37 * 2 * range.value / 100;
            new_left = 17 * 2 * range.value / 100;
        }
        else{
            new_w = 76 * 2 * range.value / 100;
            new_h = 88 * 2 * range.value / 100;
            new_top = 65 * 2 * range.value / 100;
            new_left = 223 * 2 * range.value / 100;
        }

        myimg[i].width = new_w ;
        myimg[i].height = new_h ;

        myimg[i].style.top = new_top + "px";
        myimg[i].style.left = new_left + "px";

    }
}

</script>
</head>

<body onload="load();">
    zoom : <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" id="range" onmousemove="get();"></input><span id="zoom"></span>
    <div id="box">
        <img src="img_back.jpg" alt="Girl in a jacket" alt="green" width=100% height=100%>
        <img src="img_chania.jpg" alt="Flowers in Chania" width=58px height=48px alt="green" style="position:absolute;top:37px;left:17px">
        <img src="pic_trulli.jpg" alt="Trulli" width=76px height=88px alt="green" style="position:absolute;top:65px;left:223px">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

By the way, is there any other method to implement resize and reposition pictures by using one div tag? I don't want to resize and reposition them one by one by loop. In fact, my project has one background pictures and some small pictures(not only two).

Comment: _"I don't want to resize and reposition them one by one by loop."_ - then maybe it would make more sense if you just positioned them correctly in the 100% view _once_ - and then used [`transform: scale(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale) on the container element, to zoom in/out everything together in one single step?

Answer (score 0):

A try with using almost only some css value and percentage for the scale (still some js, but little).

First the box has a position relative, the 3 images are absolute inside the box. It has a scale of 1 and an origin on top left.

We define all initial values for the img inside in CSS.
For exemple your second image was at left 223px, so in percentage of the 300px of the box, it's :
calc((223/300) * 100%)

Same for all other values with the values you had in your exemple.

First function is to init the range value and the text value.
we get the scale of the box (1 at in it), divide by 2 for range and text

changerange check the range changes.
it takes it's value, multiply 2 and 100 for the transform scale of box

```js
// init range value at 0.5, box is scale 1, so half of its scale
const initZoom = () => {
  const element = document.querySelector('#box');
  // instead of getcomputedstyle and DOMMatrix... complicated!
  // getBoundingClientRect returns the actual dimension while offsetWidth/Height is the unscaled size
  let scaleX = element.getBoundingClientRect().width / element.offsetWidth;
  // to init the range 0.5
  scaleX = (scaleX * 100) / 2;
  document.querySelector('#range').value = scaleX;
  document.querySelector('#zoom').innerHTML = scaleX + '%';
}
window.addEventListener('load', initZoom);

const changeRange = () => {
  document.getElementById('range').addEventListener('input', evt => {
    let scaleX = (document.querySelector('#range').value);
    document.querySelector('#zoom').innerHTML = scaleX + '%';
    scaleX = (scaleX * 2) / 100;
    document.querySelector('#box').style.transform = 'scale(' + scaleX + ')';
  })
}
window.addEventListener('load', changeRange);
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#box {
  position: relative;
  /* box is relative, the 3 images are absolute inside */
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  transform: scale(1);
  transform-origin: top left;
  /* to have the scale working from top left*/
}

.imgBack {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.imgUpperLeft {
  position: absolute;
  left: calc((17/300) * 100%);
  /* 17px of 300px */
  top: calc((37/300) * 100%);
  /* 37px of 300 px */
  width: calc((58/300) * 100%);
  /* 58px of 300px */
  height: calc((48/300) * 100%);
  /* 48px of 300px */
}

.imgUpperRight {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc((65/300) * 100%);
  /* 65px of 300 px */
  left: calc((223/300) * 100%);
  /* 223px of 300px */
  width: calc((76/300) * 100%);
  /* 76px of 300px */
  height: calc((88/300) * 100%);
  /* 88px of 300px */
}
```

```html
<label for="range">zoom :</label>
<input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="" id="range">
<span id="zoom"></span>

<div id="box">
  <img class="imgBack" src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/600/600" alt="Girl in a jacket" alt="green">
  <img class="imgUpperLeft" src="https://picsum.photos/id/182/200/200" alt="Flowers in Chania" alt="green">
  <img class="imgUpperRight" src="https://picsum.photos/id/75/200/200" alt="Trulli" alt="green">
</div>
```